# I am inserting chats in a database table for personal chatting but cannot show them properly

Tags: php, chat

[Here the database table where I am inserting the chats.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkiYc.png)

I am using user session to determine **sender** and using get method for the **receiver** and saving both **sender** and **receiver** in the $_SESSION['user'] and $_SESSION['receiver_user'].
When I am showing the chats, I am loading them by ajax from another php file. In that php file I am getting the value of **sender** and **receiver** by those two sessions $_SESSION['user'] and  $_SESSION['receiver_user']. 
and using the following code for showing

```
<?php  
session_start();

$user = $_SESSION['user'];

$receiver_user = $_SESSION['receiver_user'];

$m_query = "SELECT * FROM pm WHERE (sender='$user' AND receiver = '$receiver_user') OR (receiver ='$user' AND sender = '$receiver_user') ORDER BY timestamp DESC;";
$m_run = mysqli_query($con, $m_query);
   if(mysqli_num_rows($m_run)>0){
        while($m_row=mysqli_fetch_array($m_run)){
            $message = $m_row['message'];
            $user1 = $m_row['sender'];
            $user2 = $m_row['receiver'];
            $time = $m_row['timestamp'];

            if($user1==$user){





        ?>

            <li class="chat1"><h5 style=""><?php echo $us_name; ?>: <b><?php echo $message; ?></b></h5></li>
            <?php  
                    }
                    else{
            ?>
            <li class="chat2"><h5 style=""><?php echo $receiver_name ; ?>: <b><?php echo $message; ?></b></h5></li>
            <?php

                    }

                }
            }
        ?>
```

Here the value of **receiver** is saved in $_SESSION['receiver_user'], where I can only save one value. But when a user is trying to send message to two or more different people in the same time using different tabs of same browser, it showing the same message in every tabs. because the $_SESSION['receiver_user'] can only save one value. 
For example if **A** wants to send message to **B**, **C**, **D** in the same time using different tabs of browser, $_SESSION['receiver_user'] becomes either **B** or **C** or **D** 
that's why all tabs of the browser shows the same message of either **B** or **C** or **D**.

if $_SESSION['receiver_user'] = "B"
then it shows the message between **A** and **B** in all tabs. 
Now I want you to help me to solve this problem in different way.

Comment: Don't store 'receiver_user' in `$_SESSION` but use a `$_GET`-variable instead. That way you can have different chats per browser-tab, eg 'chat.php?receiver_user=B' (`$_POST` will work too if you prefer)

Comment: Following up a bit on what @PetervanderWal said, it seems like you're trying to do `client-side` features using `server-side` code.

Comment: @PetervanderWal and Derek thank you for your suggestion. It's working now perfectly. :)